# Android Developer Console: Number of installs less that active installs and do not increase. What's wrong?

Tags: android, google-play

I published free application on android market and saw the progress of installs in the first day. But then on the next day and so on my install counter stand still, but active installs are increasing.

Currently I have the following in my developer console:

- installs: 324
- active installs: 567 (175%)

I know that the number of users are increasing, **but why the first counter does not?**

Only the second one is increasing, but I think it did not take part in the public market, so I'm still in 100-500 range :(

Answer (score 6):

my stock answer:
The market statistics are by no means perfect.  They are only periodically updated, and have frequently bounced around like crazy.  When I first published an app it was actually double counting one of the stats - Google fixed the bug that caused that but didn't fix the statistics.

I've also seen people report issues with paid application statistics being inaccurate where people click to buy and the download doesn't go through, or they cancel inside the 15 min window etc..

They constantly tweek the basis for the calculation as well - with a change as recent as May 2nd

> As of May 2, 2011, we’ve changed the
>   basis for calculation of install
>   numbers provided in the Android Market
>   Developer Console. Previously, app
>   installs were calculated per user and
>   did not account for certain uninstall
>   activities (like when a device was
>   factory reset). Installs are now
>   counted per device, with duplicates
>   more effectively filtered out. This
>   offers you a more accurate measure of
>   your app distribution in the Android
>   ecosystem.
>
> You may notice that this change has
>   resulted in a one-time decrease in the
>   number of total installs for your
>   apps. We apologize for any confusion
>   this may have caused

Basically there a lots of bugs with the way they track the stats so don't trust 'em.

Comment: This is correct. There is a bad communications issue between google checkout and android market. Mine updates only once per week if im lucky

Comment: Either way, how can de dev console show a lot more installs than my merchant center? I could understand if it was missing some but having more? How is it possible? I can see the refunds in the merchant center and evven then, it doesn't reflect the amount on dev console.